# Conditional Probability of a List followed by another term NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

NO CODE NEEDED 
I am checking probability that given a series of words that, following that series, the index is some given word. I am currently working with nltk/python and was wondering if there was a simple function to do this or if I need to hard code this kind of thing myself by iterating through and counting all occurrences sort of thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over the whole text first and count the n-grams so that you can compute their probability given a preceding sequence.

Here is a very simple example:

```py
import re
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

# Tokenize the text in a very naive way.
text = "The Maroon Bells are a pair of peaks in the Elk Mountains of Colorado, United States, close to the town of Aspen. The two peaks are separated by around 500 meters (one-third of a mile). Maroon Peak is the higher of the two, with an altitude of 14,163 feet (4317.0 m), and North Maroon Peak rises to 14,019 feet (4273.0 m), making them both fourteeners. The Maroon Bells are a popular tourist destination for day and overnight visitors, with around 300,000 visitors every season."
tokens = re.findall(r"\w+", text.lower(), re.U)


def get_ngram_mapping(tokens, n):
    # Add markers for the beginning and end of the text.
    tokens = ["[BOS]"] + tokens + ["[EOS]"]

    # Map a preceding sequence of n-1 tokens to a list
    # of following tokens. 'defaultdict' is used to
    # give us an empty list when we acces a key that
    # does not exist yet.
    ngram_mapping = defaultdict(list)

    # Iterate through the text using a moving window
    # of length n.
    for i in range(len(tokens) - n + 1):
        window = tokens[i:i+n]
        preceding_sequence = tuple(window[:-1])
        following_token = window[-1]

        # Example for n=3: 'it is good' =>
        # ngram_mapping[("it", "is")] = ["good"]
        ngram_mapping[preceding_sequence].append(following_token)

    return ngram_mapping


def compute_ngram_probability(ngram_mapping):
    ngram_probability = {}
    for preceding, following in ngram_mapping.items():
        # Let's count which tokens appear right
        # behind the tokens in the preceding sequence.
        # Example: Counter(['a', 'a', 'b'])
        # => {'a': 2, 'b': 1}
        token_counts = Counter(following)

        # Next we compute the probability that
        # a token 'w' follows our sequence 's'
        # by dividing by the frequency of 's'.
        frequency_s = len(following)

        token_probability = defaultdict(float)
        for token, token_frequency in token_counts.items():
            token_probability[token] = token_frequency / frequency_s

        ngram_probability[preceding] = token_probability


    return ngram_probability

ngrams = count_ngrams(tokens, n=2)
ngram_probability = compute_ngram_probability(ngrams)

print(ngram_probability[("the",)]["elk"])  # = 0.14285714285714285
print(ngram_probability[("the",)]["unknown"]) # = 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to solve the same issue as well. I used `nltk.ngrams()` function to get n-grams and then extend into a list as bi-grams because `nltk.ConditionalFreqDist()` function requires bi-grams. Then feed the results into `nltk.ConditionalProbDist()`. You can find the following example code;

```
from collections import defaultdict

ngram_prob = defaultdict(float)
ngrams_as_bigrams=[]
ngrams_as_bigrams.extend([((t[:-1]), t[-1]) for t in nltk.ngrams(tokens, n)])

cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(ngrams_as_bigrams)
cpdist = nltk.ConditionalProbDist(cfd, nltk.LidstoneProbDist, gamma=0.2, bins=len(tokens))
for (pre,follow) in ngrams_as_bigrams:
    all_st = pre + (follow,)
    ngram_prob[all_st] = cpdist[pre].prob(follow)
sorted_ngrams = [' '.join(k) for k, v in sorted(ngram_prob.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[::-1]][:topk]
```